# Is there a way that lets you lock your screen during YouTube

Tags: lock-screens, youtube

My son likes to watch a specific YouTube video in the car sometimes, and he always touches the screen and stops the video. Is there any way to prevent this while keeping the screen on?

Comment: I've found that loading a different browser such as Firefox, then pressing the play button on a pair of headphones once the screen locks works.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to install the Touch blocking App such as [Touch Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.argotronic.touchblocker).

How this works?

> Touch Blocker prevents unintentional touch interaction with the touch
>   screen of your device by blocking touch input. When you disable touch
>   input while watching a movie you don't have to worry not to skip
>   scenes by accidentally touching the screen.

So, as soon as you begin to watch YouTube video, **Enable** touch blocker: Just need to touch notification icon to enable it.

And when you are done with Video watching, you can **disable** the touch blocking. The Touch Blocker app which is mentioned in above link has many different ways of unblocking the touch, such as pressing Volume Up button on the device.